# Kerberos based infrastructure with artifactory repo for our java artifcts with Apache reverse proxy and mod auth kerb. how can I access with gradle?

Tags: apache

We recently migrated our company to a kerberos-based infrastructure. I successfully set up an Artifactory repo for our java artifacts, with Apache reverse proxy and mod_auth_kerb. How can I access this with gradle?

Comment: This is a highly product-specific usage and config question. You might have to ask on Gradle's forums: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle

Comment: This is a very specialized question. As it is currently presented, you'd it would need to be answered by somebody with more experience than you at every technology you just mentioned, specifically Gradle. Just a suggestion, but see if you can abstract some of the details and focus your question on where Kerberos and Gradle interface with each other.